# Foreach array same keys value increment

Tags: php, arrays

I have this foreach:

```
    foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
    // processing likes array for calculating fanbase. 

    if(!empty($status['likes']['data']))
        {
            foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){
                $frid = $likesData['id']; 
                $frname = $likesData['name']; 
                $friendArray[$frid]++;
            }

        }   


print_r(array($friendArray));

}
```

The result is like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[333] => 2 
[222] => 5 
[111] => 2
[444] => 3 ))
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
[444] => 4 
[222] => 3 
[333] => 6 
[111] => 2 
))
.. etc.
```

I want to increment (or sum them) same key values. How can I do that?
And put `print_r(array($friendArray));`
outside of foreach. Thank you

Comment: `$arrary_one[0][111] + $array_two[0][111]`

Comment: I have to do this in foreach loop. There are too many values, I want to count same keys in all the arrays.

Comment: @MihalceaAlexandru, show the initial arrays

Comment: so do a `foreach($array_one as $key => $value)`, then use the $key from the first array to access the equivalent item in `$array_two`

Comment: Which variable are you showing as the result? `$friendArray` isn't a 2-dimensional array like that.

Comment: Full code update. See now

Comment: Where is `$friendArray` defined?

Comment: $friendArray is not defined

Comment: Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to define `$friendArray` at the beginning, such as

```
$friendArray = []; // initialize the array

foreach ($statuses['data'] as $status) {
    // processing likes array for calculating fanbase. 

    if (!empty($status['likes']['data'])) {
        foreach ($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData) {
            $frid = $likesData['id']; 
            $frname = $likesData['name']; 
// your version                $friendArray[$frid]++;
            if (array_key_exists($frid, $friendArray) || 0 == ($friendArray[$frid] = 0)) { 
                // always true but ensures the key is initialized
                $friendArray[$frid] ++;
            }

            isset($friendArray[$frid]) ? $friendArray[$frid] = 1 : $friendArray[$frid] ++;
        }
    }   
}

print_r($friendArray);
```